# |$deg^+ (v) - deg^- (v)$| $\le 1$.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove or disproved that for every **undirected** graph $G$, there is an orientation $D$ on $G$ such that |$deg^+ (v) - deg^- (v)$| $\le 1$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Add the minimal amount of edges to give all vertices even degree. Decompose the the graph into disjoint cycles; choose an orientation for each of them. Remove your added edges.

Comment: @Angelo: The earlier question is for undirected graphs too ... (but it's answer seems at first sight to be rather more complex than it needs to be).

Comment: @Angelo: This answer is for an undirected graph. The old question and its (apparently overcomplex) is for an undirected graph too. (It _starts by_ defining a concept of "almost balanced digraph", but the actual _question_ there is "How can I prove that every graph admits a almost-balanced orientation?" which is about "every graph", that is, implicitly undirected graphs, not digraphs).

Comment: And it makes no difference whether it's a multigraph or not. If you have a procedure that works _without_ multiple edges and have a multigraph, just insert a new vertex in the middle of each of the edges, and orient the resulting graph. The only way the _new_ vertices can then satisfy your degree condition is that the two half-edges have matching orientations which can be copied back to the edge in the original multigraph.