# Prove that an undirected graph G has an orientation in which the in/outdegree of each vertex is at most k iff max degree is less than or equal to 2k.

Tags: graph-theory

So I understand that if we prove for the largest case we can subsequently prove for any following cases they are subgraphs with the same property, but I'm having trouble proving this largest case. A hint I was given was to consider 2k-regular graphs.

Can anyone help with understanding this proof?

Comment: That's a direct corollary of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691770/deg-v-deg-v-le-1).

Comment: Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533684/how-to-prove-that-every-graph-admits-an-almost-balanced-orientation) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396009/prove-the-edges-of-a-multigraph-may-be-oriented-such-that-the-net-degree-of-any)...